# I am new to this and having issue while runing the java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm-install

Can someone help. I am completely new to this but when I am running the script I am getting below error. if someone can teach me or help me it would be a great help

> functions@ deploy /Users/kapilgaur/Downloads/React-Native-APP-master/functions
>   firebase deploy --only functions

```
sh: firebase: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kapilgaur/.npm/_logs/2020-03-05T13_09_05_478Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: looks like firebase isn't installed, Did you run this `npm i firebase` ?

Comment: You should edit this question and remove the `java` tag. Java is not JavaScript. Also edit the title, for clarity.

Comment: Try installing firebase globally: `npm i -g firebase`. Verify it by running command: `firebase`

Answer (score 0):

run this in your terminal

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

or you  just install firebase tool globally

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

either of them should do the trick,